# Same optimization algorithm resulting in different coefficients and computation time

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I noticed that when I run an optimization method in MATLAB with a [`fmincon`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) function, for example active-set method, the resulting coefficients and computation time is different every time I run the algorithm. I do not change the starting points, I just run the method one after another.

I understand this is the case for global optimization algorithms as they are using stochastic algorithms in the background. But why the same thing happens for the local minimum methods?

EDIT: adding the code

```
options = optimset('fmincon') ;
options = optimset(options,...
    'LargeScale','on',...
    'Algorithm','active-set',...
    'MaxFunEvals',10000,...
    'Display','off',...
    'TolCon', 1e-10,...
    'TolFun', 1e-10,...
    'TolX', 1e-10,...
    'MaxIter',10000) ;

[Param,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(@Cost_FCN, Param0,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options,Fz,Side,Camber,List,Coeff,Fy) ;

1.8181      1.8181
0.1737      0.1737
0.0210      0.0210
0.0004      0.0004
0.0000      0.0000
9.5810      9.5811
4.7975      4.7981
1.5981      1.5991
9.9934      9.9934
0.8277      0.8277
0.0359      0.0360
0.2438      0.2437
0.0125      0.0125
0.0051      0.0051
0.0041      0.0041
```

Bounds and constraints are constant and the starting points are the same every time I run the method.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question!

Comment: Its algorithm dependent, not global/local dependent. And even non stochastic algorithms, such as The basic Newton's method need an initial guess, that would make the algorithm behave differently. If you want consistent answers, you may need to write your own minimization

Comment: No. fmincon should be completely deterministic [link](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42119-is-fmincon-deterministic-if-so-why-am-i-getting-different-results), when giving the same parameters (including the starting-points). Running it multiple times would be a problem if it uses random-numbers internally; but as there is no seed in the parameters this should not be the case. If it would, you would need to reset the seed before each run. The error should be somewhere else. Show us the code!

Comment: What is the seed?

@AnderBiguri I know, but I mean algorithms for local and global optimisation. Most of the algorithms for global optimisation are stochastic.

Comment: @Lior Yes, which **doesn't** imply that the algorithms for local are not

Comment: That is only part of the code you posted. Not enough to help.